# Asymptotics of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^nn^{1/k}$ at $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

The asymptotics of the sum $\displaystyle S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nn^{1/k}$ can be found, for example, by means of Stolz-Césaro theorem (for example, [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-displaystyle-lim_-n-to-infty-frac1-sqrt-n-left-sum_-i-1-nn-1-i-2n-right-tag/answer/Schlitzer?comment_id=365747184&comment_type=2&__filter__=all&__nsrc__=notif_page&__sncid__=44824945766&__snid3__=59918032210)); I found it via the Euler-Maclaurin' summation formula.

The answer is
$$S_n=n+n^{1/2}+n^{1/3}+n^{1/4}+...+n^{1/n}\sim 2n+n^{1/2}+n^{1/3}+n^{1/4}+...$$
As we deal with the asymptotic series, we may expect that there is no contradiction here.

So, my questions are:

1. How many term of the asymptotics (depending on $n$) we are allowed to retain?
2. How we can evaluate (or estimate) the remainder term?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. This is almost like saying $S_n$ is asymptotic to itself. This statement is equivalent to saying that $n/S_n$ vanishes as $n\to\infty$ which is not exactly a sharp asymptotic equivalence, it is just an estimate $S_n\in\omega(n)$. Surely, you would want a better estimate in terms of something more tangible; Stirling's formula is useful, but $n!\sim n!+n$ is not.

Comment: @FShrike, I agree, it looks like a paradox. I guess the point is that in the sum we sum up all $n$ terms, but in the asymptotics we are allowed to keep less than $n$ terms. You may also evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt n}(S_n-2n)=1$

Comment: I'm just not sure what the question is. About the "allowed to retain" etc. As written this seems like a useless asymptotic estimate for $S_n$

Comment: You can get $n^{-1/k}((S_n-n)-(n+n^{1/2}+\dots+n^{1/(k-1)}))\to 1$ for all $k\geq 2$ with similar methods.  I don't know what your point is, because the extra $n$ comes from all remaining $n^{1/(k+1)},n^{1/(k+2)},\dots, n^{1/n}$ as $\geq 1$ and an estimate of their upper bound.

Comment: @FShrike, I would like to find $k(n)$, so that $$S_n=n+\sum_{i=1}^{k(n)}n^{1/i}+R(n)$$, where the remainder $R(n)=o\big(n^{1/k}\big)$ and, if possible, to get an explicite form of $R(n)$

Comment: @10354138, I'm not sure that the asymptotitics is valid for all $k\geq2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be some positive integer to be determined later, so we have

$$
S_n=\sum_{k=1}^Nn^{1/k}+\sum_{k=N+1}^nn^{1/k}.
$$

Notice that when $k>\log n$, we have $n^{1/k}=1+{\log n\over k}+O\left(\log^2n\over k^2\right)$. This indicates that when $N=\lfloor\log n\rfloor$, there is

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=N+1}^nn^{1/k}
&=\sum_{k=N+1}^n1+\sum_{k=N+1}^n{\log n\over k}+O\left(\sum_{k=N+1}^n{\log^2n\over k^2}\right) \\
&=n-N+(\log n)\log{n\over N+1}+O\left(\log n\over N\right)+O\left(\log^2n\over N\right) \\
&=n+O(\log^2n).
\end{aligned}
$$

Consequently, we have the following asymptotic expansion:

$$
S_n=2n+n^{1/2}+n^{1/3}+\dots+n^{1/\lfloor\log n\rfloor}+O(\log^2n).
$$

Comment: (+1) In $O\left(\sum_{k=N+1}^n{\log^2n\over k}\right)$ you should divide by $k^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I got the similar result (the remainder $O(\ln^2n)$), but in a more complicated way. I think your solution is the shortcut to the answer. Interestingly, we are allowed to retain a very slow growing number ($[\ln n]$) of terms in the asymptotics.

Comment: @Gary Just edited. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Svyatoslav If you are happy to take more terms then you can gain a better error term: $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {n^{1/k} }  = 2n + \bigg( {\sum\limits_{k = 2}^{\left\lfloor {\log ^2 (n)} \right\rfloor } {n^{1/k} } } \bigg) - 2\log (n)\log \log (n) + \mathcal{O}(1).
$$

Answer (score 1):

You add $n$ terms each $\ge 1$, that’s $n$ in total. The first term is $n$, the second $\sqrt n$, the third $n^{1/3}$, I bet the sum is $2n + \sqrt n + O{(n^{1/3})}$.